# tileLayers grouped in layerGroup not displaying

Tags: leaflet, basemap

I am trying to combine 3 tileLayers (Esri map services for imagery, boundaries, roads) into one layerGroup so that it can be chosen via the layers control.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vu45meq/) shows the three tileLayers initially loaded individually ok.  But the layerGroup doesn't work (the map is gray) when 'Grouped' is chosen via the L.control.layers.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add the layerGroup `combo` to the `layers` option, otherwise it is not added to the map. This is just a convenience. You can also add each layer individually, for example `combo.addTo(map)`

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [39.73, -104.99],
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [img, bnd, transport, combo]
});
```

[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1ysyLkp9/1/)

Comment: Toms: When I click one of the other basemaps, then click 'combo' in the layer control, the map is gray. I don't think your solution works. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RGWax.png)